# Hosted Exchange Impersonation ManagementRole

Tags: email, exchange-server, contacts, impersonation

I tried to create an New-ManagementRoleAssignment

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name "ImpersonationRole" -Role ApplicationImpersonation -User "Administrator@domain"
```

Next i tried to set/change RecipientOrganizationalUnitScope Organisation

```
Set-ManagementRoleAssignment ImpersonationRole -RecipientOrganizationalUnitScope Organisation
```

But Impersonation doesn`t work for Administrator@domain and an User from Organization 
with EWS...

Allways get SoapException was unhandled "The impersonation principal name is invalid."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Has the administrator full access to all the users in the organization?
Have you checked that the administator may impersonate?

Comment: Thx ;) I found the problem, the exchange was installed in hosted mode. so impersonation only works in the appropriate organisational unit.